# Array of Objects check for equality and place accordingly

Tags: javascript

I have a very interesting Problem and would like to hear some approaches that you would take.

Scenario:

A Tournament of `32` Players, each represented in an Array of Objects ex:

```
[
  { player: 'Badgy', points: 5, place: tba, reward: 0 },
  { player: 'Ceff', points: 5, place: tba, reward: 0},
  { player: 'Niclas', points: 10, place: tba, reward: 0}
]
```

Now there are prices defined for each of the top places like:

```
1 Place = 100 Coins
2 Place = 50 Coins
3 Place = 10 Coins
```

Now in this example 'Ceff' and 'Badgy' have the same point amount, which means they both have to be place 2 and get the reward of `(place2 + place3) / 2`, each of them would get 30 coins in this example.

Now I tried around but I have  a hard time finding a good solution to this case, specially if a 3+ way tie happens.

Comment: 1. Sort players by points  2. Gather (e.g. in arrays) each pointing group

Comment: I don't want to be nasty, but that doesn't really seem a "very interesting" problem to me. Anyway, you should give it a try first, as SO is not a free code writing service. Apart from that, why would you attribute 2nd and 3rd prizes to them if they are tie for the 2nd place? You should add precisions on how to attribute prize, that would seem more logical to me that they share the 2nd prize only.. what would go to the third then?

Comment: @Kaddath there is no 3rd place in that case only a 4th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a sum and an index for the first found group of same points and take the average for the last same group.

```js
var prices = [100, 50, 20, 15, 10,  5,  2,  1],
    points = [ 20, 10, 10,  5,  5,  5,  4,  3],
    sum = 0,
    index,
    profit = points.reduce((r, v, i, { [i - 1]: last }) => {
        if (last !== v) {
            sum = 0;
            index = i;
        }
        sum += prices[i];
        var avg = sum / (i - index + 1);
        while (i >= index) r[i--] = avg;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(profit);
```